# KeyError: 'observation' while trying out multi agent reinforcement learning with OpenAI stable-baselines3 and gym

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I was trying to use hungry-geese gym [here](https://www.kaggle.com/victordelafuente/dqn-goose-with-stable-baselines3-pytorch#) to train PPO:

```
from kaggle_environments import make
from stable_baselines3 import PPO

directions = {0:'EAST', 1:'NORTH', 2:'WEST', 3:'SOUTH'}
loaded_model = PPO.load('logs\\dqn2ppo_nonvec\\model')

def agent_ppo(obs, config):
    a = directions[loaded_model.predict(obs)[0]]
    return a 
    
env = make('hungry_geese',debug=True)
env.run([agent_ppo,'agent_bfs.py'])
env.render(mode="ipython")
```

But my game was getting played for only one step. After running with debug ON I got following trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\crrma\.virtualenvs\hungry_geese-ept5y6nv\lib\site-packages\kaggle_environments\agent.py", line 151, in act
    action = self.agent(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-29-faad97d317d6>", line 5, in agent_ppo
    a = directions[loaded_model.predict(obs)[0]]
  File "c:\users\crrma\.virtualenvs\hungry_geese-ept5y6nv\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\base_class.py", line 497, in predict
    return self.policy.predict(observation, state, mask, deterministic)
  File "c:\users\crrma\.virtualenvs\hungry_geese-ept5y6nv\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\policies.py", line 262, in predict
    observation = ObsDictWrapper.convert_dict(observation)
  File "c:\users\crrma\.virtualenvs\hungry_geese-ept5y6nv\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\vec_env\obs_dict_wrapper.py", line 68, in convert_dict
    return np.concatenate([observatio I was trying to use hungry-geese gym [here](https://www.kaggle.com/victordelafuente/dqn-goose-with-stable-baselines3-pytorch#) to train PPO. But my game was getting played for only one step. After running with debug ON I got following trace:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\crrma\.virtualenvs\hungry_geese-ept5y6nv\lib\site-packages\kaggle_environments\agent.py", line 151, in act
    action = self.agent(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-29-faad97d317d6>", line 5, in agent_ppo
    a = directions[loaded_model.predict(obs)[0]]
  File "c:\users\crrma\.virtualenvs\hungry_geese-ept5y6nv\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\base_class.py", line 497, in predict
    return self.policy.predict(observation, state, mask, deterministic)
  File "c:\users\crrma\.virtualenvs\hungry_geese-ept5y6nv\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\policies.py", line 262, in predict
    observation = ObsDictWrapper.convert_dict(observation)
  File "c:\users\crrma\.virtualenvs\hungry_geese-ept5y6nv\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\vec_env\obs_dict_wrapper.py", line 68, in convert_dict
    return np.concatenate([observation_dict[observation_key], observation_dict[goal_key]], axis=-1)
KeyError: 'observation'
```

So I debuged a bit more in vscode. As can be seen in below screenshot, both `observation` and `desired_goal` keys are not present in `observation_dict`.

[image]

Also this is how I debuged to above call:

[image]

Am I using API incorrectly for this to occur (am new to the API)? (or this can be a bug, which I feel highly unlikely.)

[Colab notebook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12g6Xzd2s2SlXYjjGYcgKvUgRWyVRF1rY/view?usp=sharing) and [model](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12jEUfepauRhsVRPvqZ61C25GVd1kTZUd?usp=sharing)